# How to count specific value occurrences in the same field?

Tags: splunk

I have a json splunk logs, and I need to get the count of the number of times the "message" field is equal to "Total request time", and then in the same string I will need to get a count of the number of times the "message" field is equal to "sub-request time". This same template is used for most all the logs, so the "message" field can have several different values.

```
{
  api:  my-fancy-api 
  app:  MyApp
  category:  RESP_TIME 
  message:  Total request time 
  reference_id:  MyID123123
  session_id:  1442877284-39497 
  time:  09-21-2015 23:14:45.023 +0000 
  total_request_time:  0.557 
  units:  seconds 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a pattern in my splunk commands notebook :)

You create a new field by using `eval` and conditionally assigning a `1` or `0` to it. Then you just need to sum the fields - full example below:

```
...some search commands (i.e. choose an index)...
| eval msg_total=if(message="Total request time", 1, 0)
| eval msg_subreq=if(message="sub-request time", 1, 0)
| stats sum(msg_total) as "Total messages", sum(msg_subreq) as "Subreq msgs"
```